# two male cockatiels bowing their head to each other

Tags: breeding, birds, cockatiels

i have two male cockatiels. they are pretty much good friends and get along really well. however i see them sometimes bowing their head to each other for a short time like 1 minute, then they start fighting in a specific manner, until one gets away. have you guys ever encountered such thing?

Answer (score -1):

Birds are outside my knowledge, but I am *told* that bobbing heads at each other is a friendly gesture. So my *guess* is that this translates as

"We're good?"

"We're good."

"Hey, wanna wrestle?"

"Sure."